# Phantom <div> increases document width and produces an undesired document margin on Firefox

Tags: gwt

Thanks to Firefox's 3D View I detected an empty `<div>` far outside the boundaries of my GWT 2.5.1 app's screens. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

You can see the main app screen below, a couple of outsider `<div>`s on top of it (which I attribute to the inner workings of layout panels) and above them all, the unexplained `<div>`. It is represented by the following doc element (copied from Firefox's own dev tools):

```
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: -32767; top: -20cm; width: 10cm; height: 10cm; visibility: hidden;" aria-hidden="true"> … </div>
```

The `<div>` precedes the RootLayoutPanel element (used `ensureDebugId` to find out). The problem is that it is this `<div>` that causes an undesired right margin in the app's mobile views (which have limited width). Removing this `<div>` using dev tools eliminates the problem.

Does anyone know the origin of this `<div>` and what could get rid of it?

P.S.: I tested the issue on mobile Firefox to test a theory that this might be due to one of my add-ons. Alas, also happens on the mobile Firefox 21 which has none of my add-ons installed.

### Update

A GWT project member [commented on the issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=8223#c1), not recommending the use of layout panels in mobile applications. I switched from using the `RootLayoutPanel` to using the `RootPanel` and the problem indeed went away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these divs are attributable to layout panels; they are "rulers" to detect changes in "relative units" (`em` and `ex` to detect font change –there's one such div per layout widget–; and `cm` to detect zooming –there's only one such div for the whole application–), because you can mix units when you position your "layers" in a `LayoutPanel`.

I think the `fixedRuler` (for `cm`s) should be positioned not only at `top:-20cm` but also `left:-20cm` (or possibly `right:-20cm` in RTL). Would you mind filing a bug at https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/entry ? (and possibly even providing the patch: http://www.gwtproject.org/makinggwtbetter.html)

Answer (score 3):

As a work around use this in your CSS. I have not tested it with use of aria in widgets in the app.

```
div[aria-hidden="true"] {
    right: 0cm;
}
```

But it will remove the horizontal scroll bar on mobile apps on iPhone and such.